# Extensions on AKS VMSS

Tags: azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set

Can we install extensions on VMSS deployed for AKS, specifically

OmsAgentForLinux,
LinuxDiagnostic,
DependencyAgent,
BootDiag

I am not seeing any concrete information around this and as per my interpretation the consensus seems to be not to make any changes to the resources deployed in MC Resource Group.

Thanks!

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you said, it's not recommended to change the things in the node resource group. You can see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-use-custom-vm-extensions).

It's not recommended. But if you really want to install the extension, you can also do it. You need to receive the bad result it will cause. Or maybe you can use the [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine). You can control all the things you want.

Comment: I tried installing extension but I am not able to install extension on vmss and get below error and the linked subscription is not even in our tenant.
The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/images/versions/read' on scope, however the current 
tenant is not authorized to access linked subscription

Comment: @user14173614 Obviously, you need to have the permission of the subscription you want to use, at the least the write permission. You can use the built-in role Contributor.

Comment: The subscription it is referring is not owned by us, I am owner on both the VMSS and Log Analytics Workspace subscription.

Subscription 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy' is not owned by us and we dont host it in our tenant 

az : The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/images/versions/read' on scope 
'/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/vmss', however the current tenant 'tenantid' is not 
authorized to access linked subscription 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy'.

Comment: @user14173614 Whatever, you need to have the permission to deploy the extension on the VMSS. Not for the whole subscription. Or you cannot install the extension.